# Jira - restrict access to Issue for project users

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Does anybody know a plugin/extension for `jira`, which has the following feature:

- I can restrict, e.g. while creating an issue, the access of a specific user or user group in a project. The user/group cannot access/see this issue at the end.

An Example:

```
-> Jira Project "CustomerABC"

-> Groups in this project with read/write rights: company-members, external(customerABC)

-> Issue 1234 "Testissue" read/write for group company-members and  hidden 
   for group external(customerABC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `Issue Security Scheme`, create new security level saying which  **Users / Groups / Project Roles** can access issues with this level set.

Then set this scheme in you project under `Issue Security`.

While creating issue it is possible to set `Security Level` field.

We use this concept for EU data protection where people outside EU can't see EU customer data.

Comment: Do you hide fields for external groups?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean, but for EU DP we don't show these issues at all.